# How to create vocabulary page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want want to create page for vocabulary. I mean not vocabulary term, but vocabulary name.

```
mysite.com/myvocab
```

rather than

```
mysite.com/myvocab/term
```

That page should also have possibility to display text (how can I add text field to vocabulary and not vocab term?)

Thanks!

Comment: what contents you need to be displayed in mysite.com/myvocab... List of nodes referred this vocabulary? or Terms inside it?.. Pls mention it in your question

Comment: I have set of vocabularies. On each vocabulary page I need to display list of nodes referred to vocabulary, list of terms and some text.

Comment: First, make a view for showing your terms. Secondly,
set the value of formatter in the field setting of the views design page, as "Plain Text"

Comment: You can even make a page for view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two simple way to do it I think :

1. Use [Vocabulary](https://www.drupal.org/project/vocabulary) module which gives you the taxonomy/vid page.
2. Or Use views to create your page. Create a taxonomy type view and add `Taxonomy vocabulary: Vocabulary ID` or `Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine Name` as argument.
3. If you want to display the nodes related to vocabulary then I think you need to use [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) with 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right about views. And how can I add text to each vocabulary?

Comment: I think `Taxonomy vocabulary: Description` can do that.

Comment: I marked your answer as best cause I think it's full, though I at current moment complete step 3 (I created page view mysite/vocabulary/% with terms for the vocabulary but I don't understand how to embed nodes related to vocabulary view)

Comment: I must create Context Filter vocabulary machine name and then create View with terms belonging to vocabulary machine name and embed it into main view, right?

Comment: After enabling the Views Field View you will be able to see the `Global Views` field in views field list. You can add the another view in which contextual filter of tid is added.

Comment: Yes, but how can I pass tid to second view? First I create View with page mysite/vocabulary/% (where % is vocabulary name not tid, this view shows all terms for vocabulary which it gets from Context filter) and create Context filter vocabulary machine term. How can I pass tid?

Comment: Add tid field, exclude it and pass it using token.

Comment: Thanks, I did it! You really saved my day! Great, great thanks!!!

Comment: And I don't have rights now to upvote your answer(

Comment: Glad it helps... :)